# Locally monotone function is monotone

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions

A function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is *locally monotone* at point $a$ iff there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $f|_{]a-\epsilon;a+\epsilon[}$ is monotone ($x\ge y\Rightarrow f(x)\ge f(y)$ for all points $x$, $y$ of $]a-\epsilon;a+\epsilon[$).

**Question** If a function is locally monotone at all points of real line (or more generally an interval on real line), then it is monotone on the entire real line (or more generally, on this interval)?

If it does not hold for any intervals, does it hold for closed intervals?

Comment: Yes, locally monotone implies monotone, basically because $\mathbb{R}$ is connected. Your job is to prove this, I presume :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $I$ be an order-convex subset of $\Bbb R$, and suppose that $f:I\to\Bbb R$ is locally monotone. For $a,b\in I$ write $a\sim b$ iff either $a\le b$ and $f$ is monotone on $[a,b]$, or $b<a$ and $f$ is monotone on $[b,a]$; $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $I$. $I$ is connected, and it follows from the local monotonicity of $f$ that each $\sim$-equivalence class is open, so $I$ must be a $\sim$-class, and $f$ is monotone on $I$.

Comment: It doesn't get much better -- anyway, it doesn't get more succinct! No pesky epsilons. Very nice.

Comment: I don't get why $I$ must be a $\sim$-class

Comment: @porton: If not, let $[a]$ be some $\sim$-class. Then $[a]$ and $I\setminus[a]$ are a partition of $I$ into open sets, contradicting the connectedness of $I$.

Comment: @porton If there were multiple $\sim$-eq classes, they would form an open partition of $I$; but $I$ is connected.